# Is there an Jquery dropdown menu that drops down on top of other frames in a framset?

Tags: jquery

I've tried some dropdown menus, but they drop behind other frames.

Comment: That isn't possible.  You cannot escape your frame.

Comment: Isn't `z-index` (CSS) a solution?

Comment: Why would you still use frames with so many better solutions available now?

Comment: @t.j. crowder have a look at this please. im asking how to convert to iframes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261989/how-can-i-convert-this-to-iframes

Answer (score 0):

Frames, by definition, are other documents. Going outside a frame would be like asking to render something outside the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with traditional frames, full stop.

This *can* be done with `iframe`s, using z-index, but only if all of the frames in question are `iframes`. In fact, using `iframes` in this way is a key part of "modal" dialogs and the like.

But traditional frames in a frameset, no.

Comment: have a look at this please. im asking how to convert to iframes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261989/how-can-i-convert-this-to-iframes