# How can i convert this to iFrames

Tags: html

```
</head>
    <frameset id="frameMain" rows="84,*" framespacing="0">
       <frame src="bannerFrame.html" id="mail" name="mail" frameborder="0" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no"/>
       <frameset id="frameSet" cols="126,*" framespacing="0">
           <frame src="leftNavigation.html" id="leftnav" name="leftnav" frameborder="0" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no"/>
           <frame src="empty.htm" id="main" name="main" frameborder="0" border="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="yes"/>
       </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Badly. If we ignore all the problems of frames, the two tools are designed for different purposes and cannot (and should not) be simply substituted for each other.

Comment: @David Dorward when i say im using framset people tell me to change to iframe now im trynig to change to iframe you're telling me i shouldnt?

Comment: @David, I don't agree. It's easy to simulate frames using a series of well positioned iframes, and furthermore, frames are deprecated alltogether, so it's either iframes or a wholesale redesign. (I admit I'd lean towards the latter.)

Comment: @user521180 — framesets have problems. iframes have overlapping problems. Trying to get the effect of a frameset with iframes just gives you the worst of both worlds. In most situations where framesets are in use, I'd recommend a wholesale redesign.

Comment: @Kirk — OK, I'll proviso the "cannot" with "sanely".

Comment: @david you're not suggesting anything contructive

Comment: @user: Perhaps it would be useful to say *why* you want this to use frames at all? I can think of a reason (and it's the reason I think deprecating frames was the wrong thing to do; there remain edge cases where they're the best option), but I don't want to put words in your mouth, I'd like to know what the *actual design problem* is **you're** trying to solve by using frames (traditional or iframe).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder The problem is. my drop downs from the banner frame is behind the other frames. i want it to be on top of the other drames when it drops down

Comment: @user521180 — You haven't constructed a question that makes a truly constructive answer easy. You're trying to simulate a problematic thing with a technology designed for a different purpose because "people" have told you to. All that can really be said to that is "don't".

Comment: @user: No, that's an *effect* of the solution (frames) you're currently using. *Why* does the page need to be broken up into frames *at all*, whether traditional frames or `iframes`? What's the purpose of the "main" frame? What do you put in it? Why can't it just be a `div` or similar?

Comment: @david ok thanks david now i can go sit down and do nothing

Comment: @David, @user: Guys, can we dispense with all the chaff? @user: FYI, David's an incredibly knowledgeable and helpful person, it's worth listening to him, even if you can't apply the advice to your current situation (which remains to be seen), or even if you end up disagreeing with him. @David: Derision doesn't suit you. :-)

Comment: Why was this question voted down? Even though it might be the wrong question, and the goal is not something you'd advise someone to work towards, the question itself is neither unclear nor inappropriate imo.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, I think converting to an iFrame is not the way to go. The way frames and iframes behave make them hard to work with in a lot of situations, and often make developing and maintainting your website a lot harder than it should be.

Maybe you should try and ask another question. It should involve the initial problem you're having (the one where people advised you to switch to iframes in the first place) and see what solutions the people here come up with. For almost every problem there will be at least one good answer that doesn't involve using frames or iframes (with a few rare exceptions).

Bottom line: you're asking the wrong question. We can probably help solve your original problem in a better way if you don't insist on using iframes.

Comment: This is a comment, though, not an answer. :-) (And BTW, I agree with you on the "why the downvote" thing, although I suppose a bit of "and here's what I've tried that hasn't worked" would be good.)

Comment: @user: If you answered my question starting *"No, that's an effect of the solution..."* or Stephan's question(s) above, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to divide a page into a header with determined length, a left navbar with a determined width and a rest area with remaining 100% width, height. You could try this: (Using pure css, natural flow, avoiding relative, absolute positioning and float, except for old IE)

1. Pad the parent div with dimensions of the header / navbar
2. Then display the children and applying CSS3 boxsizing property and subsequently
3. Undo the padding by applying a negative margin to the (first) child

Border and background for demonstration purposes.
Output written with display:inline-block, except for (old) IE.
Font-size:0 to prevent white space after iframe.
Nothing original here, but rather subtle coding.

CSS

```
html, body  { height: 100%; margin:0;}
#container  { width:64em; margin:0 auto; }
#header     { background-color:steelblue; height: 5em; width:auto /*!*/;
          text-align:center; padding-top: 1px
        /* keep text within header to prevent scroll bar in body */; }
#navbar     { background-color:lightgrey; width:10em; text-align: center;}
.bbox   { box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box }
.disnav { -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;
          *display: block; *float:left}
.vat    { font-size: 0; vertical-align:top;} /* anti scroll in IE */
.padlt  { padding: 5em 0px 0px 10em} /* reserve space for bbox to crop  */
.undoleft { margin-left: -10em }     /* Undo padding and move to left */
.undotop  { margin-top: -5em }       /* Undo padding and move to top */
.h100   { height: 100% }         /* For iframe to extend vertically */ 
.w100   { width: 100% }          /* Fot iframe to extend horizontally */
.gapless { margin:0;}            /* to keep it simple */
.border  { border:thick dotted red;
          *border:0; };              /* no border for old IE */
```

HTML

```
</head>
<body class="h100 bbox border">
    <div id="container" class="h100 padlt bbox" >
    <div id="header"
         class="w100 undoleft undotop bbox" >
         <h1>Top Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" 
         class="h100 undoleft disnav bbox border"> 
         <h1>Navbar here</h1>
    </div><!--no Wspace here--><iframe  
                    id="content"
                        name="content" 
                    class="h100 w100 gapless vat bbox border"
                    src="http://www.bbcnews.com">  
        <p> Browser does not support inline frames
        </p></iframe><!--no Wspace here--></div>
</body></html>
```